# admin.logentry: 'user' has a relation with model <class 'api.models.User'>, which has either not been installed or is abstract

Tags: django, django-admin

django 1.5.1

I create custom auth model:

file api/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):

  token = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False, help_text=_('Photo for carte'), unique=True)
  updated_token = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, help_text=_('Create record'))

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

  objects = MyUserManager()

  def __unicode__(self):
      return "пользователь: %s" % self.email
  class Meta:
      app_label = 'custom_auth'
```

file settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_auth.User'
.....
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'api',
.....
'south',
'django.contrib.admin',
```

)

on ./manage.py syncdb I get an error:

```
admin.logentry: 'user' has a relation with model <class 'api.models.User'>, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

How decide this problem?

**Edit 1**
tried comment line and make syncdb:

```
'django.contrib.admin',
```

syncdb was successful
after that tried create user in ./manage.py shell

```
In [1]: from api.models import User
In [2]: User.objects.create_superuser('test@test.com', 'test')
```

and recieve error:

```
DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'app_name.custom_auth_user' doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set an `app_label` on your class which is also in your `INSTALLED_APPS`: either set `app_label = 'api'` (the default), or add `'custom_auth'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` (of course, it needs to be a valid app then).

The validation process in Django tries to get the new User class using `get_model`, and by default `get_model` returns models for installed apps only. You can verify with your current code:

```
>>> loading.get_model('custom_auth', 'user')
>>> loading.get_model('custom_auth', 'user', only_installed=False)
  > api.models.User
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add your Meta app_label description to the INSTALLED_APPS:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'custom_auth',
)
```